# writing pyspark data frame to text file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark data frame which I created from one table in sql server and
I did some transformation on that and now I am going to convert it to
dynamic data frame in order to be abale to save it as a text file
in s3 bucket. when I am writing data frame to text file I am going to
add another header to that file.

This is my dynamic data frame that will be saved as a file:

```
AT_DATE | AMG_INS | MONTHLY_AVG

2021-03-21 | MT.0000|  234.543

2021_02_12| MT.1002 |  34.567
```

I want to add another header on top of that while I am saving my text file I need to add another row like this:

```
HDR,FTP,PC

AT_DATE,AMG_INS,MONTHLY_AVG

2021-03-21,MT.0000,234.543

2021_02_12,MT.1002,34.567
```

This is separate row that I need to add on top of my text file.

Comment: Can you provide the code you already have?

Answer (score 1):

To save your dataframe as a text file with additional headers lines, you have to perform the following steps:

#### Prepare your data dataframe

- as you can only write to text one column dataframes, you first concatenate all values into one `value` column, using [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#concat_ws) spark SQL function
- then you drop all columns but `value` column using `select` dataframe method
- you add an `order` column with literal value `2`, it will be used later to ensure that headers are at the top of the output text file

#### Prepare your header dataframe

You create a `headers` dataframe, containing one row per desired headers. Each row having two column:

- a `value` column containing the header as a string
- an `order` column containing the header order as an int (`0` for the first header and `1` for the second header)

#### Write the union of headers and data dataframes

- you union your first dataframe with the `headers` dataframe using `union` dataframe method
- you use `coalesce(1)` dataframe method to have only one text file as output
- you order your dataframe by your `order` column using `orderBy` dataframe method
- you drop your order column
- and you write the resulting dataframe

#### Complete code

Translated into code, it gives you below code snippet. I call your dynamic dataframe `output_dataframe` and your spark session `spark` and I write to `/tmp/to_text_file`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = output_dataframe \
    .select(F.concat_ws(',', F.col("AT_DATE"), F.col("AMG_INS"), F.col("MONTHLY_AVG")).alias('value')) \
    .withColumn('order', F.lit(2))

headers = sparkSession.createDataFrame([('HDR,FTP,PC', 0), ('AT_DATE,AMG_INS,MONTHLY_AVG', 1)], ['value', 'order'])

headers.union(data) \
    .coalesce(1) \
    .orderBy('order')\
    .drop('order') \
    .write.text("/tmp/to_text_file")
```